# i can't connect with any server in my computer

Tags: php, server, visual-studio-2019

I have tried many server software but none of them work for me

I tried Xampp, EsayPHP, and UwAmp too

But it doesn't work, I always get an "access denied."

and Show me this page

[image]

And when trying to write a PHP line in visual studio

Inside the HTML page like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>    <?php
    echo "My first PHP script!";
    ?> </p>

</body>
</html>
```

I see a blank HTML page!

And when I create a PHP page and try to run it, that page appears
[image]

Even when I try to activate MySQL in Visual Studio2019, this error appears

"Host 'computer-name' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

I spend days trying to solve this problem to no avail,

Please help me..

Comment: this is not enough information to fix the problem

Comment: please share some more information   like-- what is your configuration file of apache , how you are configuring php module and wht is the permission of the directory where your are executing php script

Comment: @RDX i use visual studio2019 , I downloaded PHP tools and , I downloaded many servers, but none of them are working properly with my device, for example Xampp showed me this error

"error: apache shutdown unexpectedly this may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method press the logs button to view error logs and check the windows event viewer for more clues if you need more help, copy and post this entire log window on the forums "

I don’t know what exactly is wrong, but I think that because of something in my computer

Comment: the RTC of my device also needs to be changed. I don’t know if this is relevant.

Comment: first uninstall all the server software and install fresh xampp and also turn off you iis service and try to restart your xampp. If it is showing error again, plese share your log file

Comment: i think the port you want to use in xampp server  is in use by any other application